# My dwarves have turned into gummi-bears!

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So I'm playing a succession game, using just about the latest version of DF. I just received the save file and my dwarves have turned into Gummi-Bears. I had been using the Ironhand tileset without trouble, and we have only been passing the region file (from /data/save/region1). What can I do to fix this?

Here are before and after photos:

[image: Before the Gummification!][image: After Gummification!]

Comment: You don't remember changing anything between games?

Comment: It's a succession game, and this is only my second turn.

Comment: Are they now bouncing here and there and everywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Region files passed around include RAWs, and the raws also contain the graphics files for creature tiles -- like your dwarves (Check the Region/raw/Graphics subdirectory).

This just means that whoever passed you the succession folder was using a different graphics set.

What I'd do is copy the Graphics folder from one of your saves, and just use it to overwrite the succession game's Graphics folder. You won't overwrite anything relevant to the save file, but you will turn your dwarves back into the familiar icons you're used to.

Comment: That did the trick!